# Use Python- Selenium to select span style object

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

Team,

I am trying to select one table object using `python` + `selenium-webdriver`. I tried to use the following method but it is not working:

```
select = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), 'ALL_incidents')]"))
```

This is the HTML:
[image: HTML]

Comment: Show us `HTML` for your target element.

Comment: I have added image  http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHdlj.jpg

Comment: Why do people keep posting code as images?

Comment: Rather than posting images of text (HTML, code, etc.), please post the text itself. It will make it easier on those trying to help to reuse the text using copy/paste and will prevent the case where images are lost in the future rendering the question useless. When posting HTML or code, please make sure you properly indent and format them as code. Help on formatting can be found in the How to Format panel on the right side of the editor along with more detailed help contained in the links at the bottom.

Comment: Jeff/m02ph3u5, thanks for suggestion, i will try to follow your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following `XPath`:

```
//td/nobr/span[text()="ALL_incidents"]
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson Let me try and get back to you